# Запись в новую строку textBox

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Есть цикл, в конце которого значение записывается в textbox. Мне нужно, чтоб значения записывались в новую строку, а не накладывались друг на друга.

Пробовал так:

```
textBox2->Text = Environment::NewLine + m;
```

Заранее спс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `=` на `+=`.

**UPD:** Код

```
textBox2->Text += Environment::NewLine + m;
```

где `m` это строка, должен изменять текст внутри элемента управления, а именно: добавить перенос строки и строку `m`. Для того, чтобы увидеть результаты, свойство `Multiline` должно быть выставлено как `true`.

Другим вариантом может служить вызов метода [`AppendText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx):

```
textBox2->AppendText(Environment::NewLine + m);
```

Comment: хмм так вообще ничего не добавляет

Comment: все равно не робит =(

Comment: тупо не появляется результат хоть Multiline выставлено как true.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, кому-то поможет: нашел вот такое решение для Powershell, через метод AppendText. Думаю, что подойдет и для .net

```
$button1_Click = {buttonclick}

function buttonclick ($parameter1, $parameter2)
{
    $b = ""
    $serv = Get-Process | where { $_.mainWindowTItle } | %{ $_.Name }

    ForEach ($a in $serv)
    {
        $a.ToString()
        $b = $a.ToString() + "`n"
        $textbox1.AppendText($b)

    }
```